# Saber lo que pasa en mi aplicación

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Tengo una aplicación que cuando se ejecuta realiza muchas tareas en las cuales me interesa saber si fueron ejecutadas o no (quién las hace es importante, usuarios). Yo uso un archivo y ahí guardo todo lo que sucede, pero supongo que existe algo mas sofisticado que eso no? Si se guardan a nivel de sistema operativo?

Un poco de mi código:

```
string Usuario = "", Accion = "";
StreamWriter MiArchivillo = new StreamWriter("Path");

if(Accion=="Hizo cosa1")
    MiArchivillo.WriteLine(Usuario + "Hizo cosa1");

if (Accion == "Hizo cosa2")
    MiArchivillo.WriteLine(Usuario + "Hizo cosa2");

if (Accion == "Error")
    MiArchivillo.WriteLine(Usuario + "Paso Error");

MiArchivillo.Close();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Claro PepeS. Trabajar con un archivo es una buena idea, aunque también lo puedes hacer con los eventos de Windows. De esta manera, quien se siente en la computadora será la persona de la que se guarde información. Te dejo un código:

```
 class Program
    {
        public const string Source = "MyConsoleApplication";
        public const string LogName = "MyCustomLog";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int NumberOfTurns = 0;

            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(Source))
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(Source, LogName);

            do
            {
                //When you have an error in your application
                if (NumberOfTurns == 0)
                    EventLog.WriteEntry(Source, GetMesssage("Error"), EventLogEntryType.Error, 111, 20);

                else if(NumberOfTurns ==1)
                    EventLog.WriteEntry(Source, GetMesssage("FailureAudit"), EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit, 222,21);

                //When your application executed something without problems
                else if (NumberOfTurns == 2)
                    EventLog.WriteEntry(Source, GetMesssage("Information"), EventLogEntryType.Information, 333,22);

                else if (NumberOfTurns == 3)
                    EventLog.WriteEntry(Source, GetMesssage("SuccessAudit"), EventLogEntryType.SuccessAudit, 444,23);

                //When your application found something suspect at the moment to ran
                else if (NumberOfTurns == 4)
                    EventLog.WriteEntry(Source, GetMesssage("Warning"), EventLogEntryType.Warning, 555,24);

                NumberOfTurns++;

            } while (NumberOfTurns<5);


        }


        public static string GetMesssage(string MessageType)
        {
            if (MessageType == "Error")
                return "The application fail";

            else if (MessageType == "FailureAudit")
                return "There is something wrong";

            else if (MessageType == "Information")
                return "The operation was executed successfully";

            else if (MessageType == "SuccessAudit")
                return "The application run ok";

            else 
                return "Warning: Behavior suspect";
        }
    }
```

Ya los resultados los ves desde: Herramientas Administrativas > Visor de Eventos > Registros de Windows

Comment: Lo acabo de funcionar, me esta funcionando. Gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Lo que buscas se llama libreria o framework para Logging. Estas librerias permiten:

- Escribir mensajes con distinto nivel de severidad (INFO, DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL o GRAVE, entre otros), para ayudar a la evaluacion del mensaje
- Configurar el formato en que se escribiran estos mensajes p.e. agregar fecha y hora, nombre e identificado del hilo en cuestion, entre otros
- Configurar la salida donde se escribiran los mensajes: consola, archivo, base de datos, etc
- En caso de que la salida sea a un archivo, configurar la estrategia de escritura del archivo: al alcanzar un cierto peso (en KB, MB o mas), al terminar el dia crear un nuevo archivo, etc.

Para .Net existen varias librerias que puedes utilizar, entre ellas

- [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)
- [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Puedes encontrar una lista mas extensa [aca](http://www.dotnetlogging.com/). Las librerias mencionadas tambien se encuentran en esta lista, pero de las que he revisado, esas 2 parecen tener un trabajo mas activo hasta la fecha.

Answer (score 3):

El camino que estas tomando es el correcto, no esta mal guardar en un archivo de log las acciones de la aplicacion.

Como comenta @Luiggi en lugar de crear tu mismo el código que escriba en el archivo existen librerias que pueden configurar para habilitar o no el log cuando necesites, `Log4Net` es la mas conocida.

**>>Si se guardan a nivel de sistema operativo?**

Si la idea es guardar en el sistema operativo podrias usar el `Event View`, al cual accedes desde el `Control Panel` en las `Administrative tools` .
Para escribir en el log de windows usarias las clases de `.NET` proporciona: `EventLog` que estan bajo el namespace `System.Diagnostics`.

[Working With EventViewer Using C# For Beginners](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/working-with-eventviewer-using-C-Sharp-for-beginners/)

---

Algo que no podía dejar de mencionar se relaciona a que si implementas librerias como Log4Net estas en su configuración permiten cambiar el destino de log dinamicamente, no solo estas limitadas en archivos de texto, puedes tambien loguear en el `EventView` de windows

[Log4Net - writing to windows event log with ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20200111114740/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/TimH/archive/2006/04/13/75063.aspx)

Solo tienes que definir en el configuracion el `EventLogAppender` por esta razon es que estas librerias son tan populares, no tocas nada del código y puedes cambiar donde quieres registrar als entradas del log.

Comment: Creo que esto sería lo ideal, que se guarden y puedan visualizarse dentro del Event Viewer.

Comment: @Elenasys eso depende. Quizas el o los usuarios que quieren acceder a revisar esta informacion no sean los administradores del sistema, por ello que los logs se pueden crear en una carpeta compartida con permisos para ciertos usuarios y desde ali se revisen a medida, sin necesidad de acceder directamente al servidor. Pero como siempre, en este mundo del software, todo depende

Answer (score 1):

Yo opino que es mucho mejor dejar un log de archivo que el eventlog
Ahora me tope una aplicación que aunque dice que escribe, en el eventlog no aparece en determinadas circunstancias. y nadie sabe porqué.
El eventviewer se cae, se borran  los registros mas antiguos y es un parto buscar cualquier cosa.
el eventlog solo sirve para ir registrando errores muy generales, pero para algo mas detallado no le hace el peso a un registro de archivo